# how to commit github using php

Tags: php, git, github, yii

I would like to add and commit to local git repository using PHP code

I new babies in github ,so I don't understand in path on github
path git.exe at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_054f2e797ebafd44a30203088cd3d58663c627ef\libexec\git-core

path of repo 
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\confre

```
    $path = "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\confre"; 
chdir($path);
echo shell_exec("git add . ");  
echo shell_exec("git commit -m 'commit form php' ");
```

it don't work. Help me pls

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use http://github.com/kbjr/Git.php it work!

```
require_once('Git.php');  
$repo = Git::open('gitphp');  // -or- Git::create('/path/to/repo')
$repo->run(' config  user.email "your email"'); 
$repo->run(' config  user.name "your username"');   
echo $repo->run(' log -p');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try configure git commit with author's parameters, it works fine to me:

```
shell_exec('git -c user.name="www-data" -c user.email="no-replay@example.org" commit -m "commit form php" ');
```

The errors can be found in the server error file: /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
```